# file reallocation tool for ntfs

Tags: filesystems

I have an XP Virtual Machine and some of the files on the disk are allocated after a long free space, so when i try to reduce the size of the harddisk file of the VM.

I tried to defrag the disk but it jus put most of the file at the first sectors of the disk and left the other files almost at the end of the disc.

Do you know a tool, or a way to, that allow me to move this files closer to the others at the beginig of the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to move the files? If it's to make space on the hard drive for a new partition, then you want a partition resizing tool. [`gparted`](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) is an easy to use, free graphical partition manager. It supports NTFS resizing - see [this tutorial](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/larry/resize/resizing.htm) for an example. There are [lots of others](http://www.thefreecountry.com/utilities/partitioneditors.shtml), but `gparted` is the only one I have direct experience with.